# unrecognized selector sent to instance error in IOS App using Parse API

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to learn Ios app development by developing a simple app that takes input from user and saves it in cloud using Parse API.

The input fields are firstName and lastName.

The API works well, I have tested it (hardcoded the value to be saved instead of taking it from screen). How ever, the error arises only when I am trying to take the input from the screen and save it.

Following is the code:

```
viewcontroller.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController    

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastName;

- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
    //*** Following works as I have hard coded the values to be stored and when I click directly on the save button.  ***//
    //*** But I want to get the content in firstName and lastName and save them using Parse API ***//
-     (IBAction)saveButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"NimbleIOS"];
    testObject[@"FirstName"] = @"frst";// _firstName.text;
    testObject[@"LastName"] = @"lst";// _lastName.text;
    [testObject saveInBackground];
}

@end


error: 

2014-11-19 22:38:45.229 Nimble[11714:541175] -[ViewController firstName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe568e36160
2014-11-19 22:38:45.234 Nimble[11714:541175] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController firstName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe568e36160'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd57f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c9f0bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd5f04d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccb727c ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccb6e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x000000010d1458be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
6   UIKit                               0x000000010d24c410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
7   UIKit                               0x000000010d8784cb -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 256
8   UIKit                               0x000000010d2bb47b -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 114
9   UIKit                               0x000000010d8782d4 -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 114
10  UIKit                               0x000000010d2bb265 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 284
11  UIKit                               0x000000010d1b0e03 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 99
12  UIKit                               0x000000010d877ad7 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
13  UIKit                               0x000000010d4ff9c1 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 177
14  UIKit                               0x000000010d501a30 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 2263
15  UIKit                               0x000000010d4f72e6 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 262
16  UIKit                               0x000000010d4f5f89 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 532
17  UIKit                               0x000000010d4faba6 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke662 + 51
18  UIKit                               0x000000010d4faaa2 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 254
19  UIKit                               0x000000010d4f0b1d _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2796
20  UIKit                               0x000000010d18aff6 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
21  UIKit                               0x000000010d18bc23 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
22  UIKit                               0x000000010d1589b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
23  UIKit                               0x000000010d165a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
24  UIKit                               0x000000010d141103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc8d551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc8341d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc82a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc82486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
29  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001102429f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
30  UIKit                               0x000000010d144420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
31  Nimble                              0x000000010b545d43 main + 115
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ea1c145 start + 1
33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Can some one help me know the mistake I am committing ?
I have referenced the two text fields and the save button from mainstoryboard to viewcontroller. 
I get the error after typing in the text field and moving away from it(EditingDidEnd) and touch else where on the screen.

Comment: The error message shows that you have invoked the `firstName` method on your view controller but that property/method isn't known in that class. Are you sure that message is being generated by the code shown here?  Set an exception breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator and see which line it stops on

Comment: this code should work, problem is not there

Comment: @Paulw11 : Hey, thanks for looking, I have updated the post with the entire error message.

Comment: It looks like you have an action in your storyboard or nib linked to a method that doesn't exist in your ViewController class

Comment: @Paulw11: Actually I added the editingDidEnd event, when I removed it, the code works fine, now I need to lean how to add a spinner and take inputfrom it and clear the screen after clicking the save. Thanks a lot for helping me debug it :)

Answer (score 0):

where is the firstName: method?
I only see an IBAction method named saveButton:
ie: saveButton is the @selector() not firstName:
I think you need to look at your outlets in interface builder and see if there is an old outlet still attached named firstName: which doesn't match the string literal of "FirstName"

I haven't worked with the PFObject class

I think you're trying to do something like this though

```
-(IBAction)saveButton:(UIButton *)sender{
    if([sender.restorationIdentifier isEqualToString: @"res string from IB"]){
    ...take string from input source as a string and use it
    maybe grab something from a textField or whatever
    }else if...

}
```

also you may want to make sure the sender is in fact a UIButton I see you have id listed in your public api and I just read the bottom where it says you're leaving a textField which is not an instance of UIButton!!!

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally added the "EditingDidEnd" in the sent events. The code was expecting something to happen as soon as the editing ended in the text field. The code works fine now. (I have written what I understood while trying to make the code work. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong :) )